# GitHub Build container image gives an error

Tags: git, docker, github, github-actions

I'm learning about CDs by following the training [GitHub Actions: Publish to GitHub Packages](https://lab.github.com/githubtraining/github-actions:-publish-to-github-packages).

So I created a Dockerfile, but it fails to build. I don't understand why this error is happening. How can you solve it?

I'm only using the source code presented by the bot so far, so it's hard to think of a simply typo.

https://github.com/CreatorOfWhileStudying/github-actions-for-packages/pull/3

This is an excerpt of the error message.

```
Logging in to registry docker.pkg.github.com
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /github/home/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
Login Succeeded
Building image [docker.pkg.github.com/CreatorOfWhileStudying/github-actions-for-packages/tic-tac-toe:sha-05b1cf1]
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

invalid argument "docker.pkg.github.com/CreatorOfWhileStudying/github-actions-for-packages/tic-tac-toe:sha-05b1cf1" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
See 'docker build --help'.
Error: exit status 125
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [`.github/workflows/cd-workflow.yml`](https://github.com/CreatorOfWhileStudying/github-actions-for-packages/blob/05b1cf17745ae73e76529b959915eaa6bc4587fc/.github/workflows/cd-workflow.yml#L66) mentions:

```
    - name: Build container image
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v1
      with:
        username: ${{github.actor}}
        password: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
        registry: docker.pkg.github.com
        repository: CreatorOfWhileStudying/github-actions-for-packages/tic-tac-toe
        tag_with_sha: true
```

The repository part is not compatible with a docker build, as the [logs for that action](https://pipelines.actions.githubusercontent.com/7AkzKp2mLRZO4SpvLJNg92etsOOXLWL9067NuIY0lvCPBdFeXi/_apis/pipelines/1/runs/1/signedlogcontent/39?urlExpires=2020-09-17T07%3A06%3A05.4413740Z&urlSigningMethod=HMACV1&urlSignature=IMIyHI9RERmUuSqRzQ1DSeFslXTxBJ7IzlbL5uFcDKs%3D) illustrate:

```
2020-09-17T06:09:53.7368087Z Building image [docker.pkg.github.com/CreatorOfWhileStudying/github-actions-for-packages/tic-tac-toe:sha-05b1cf1]
2020-09-17T06:09:53.7369825Z https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
2020-09-17T06:09:53.7370487Z 
2020-09-17T06:09:53.7551260Z invalid argument "docker.pkg.github.com/CreatorOfWhileStudying/github-actions-for-packages/tic-tac-toe:sha-05b1cf1" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
2020-09-17T06:09:53.7552333Z See 'docker build --help'.
2020-09-17T06:09:53.7573573Z Error: exit status 125
```

The error comes from the GitHub Action [`docker/build-push-action`](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action), like in [issue 37](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/issues/37).
Try and use `docker/build-push-action@v2`.